# I want my reactive state to be same (updated) between various tabs (unfocused), when it gets updated in any tab in Vue 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, browser-tab

Code in my template

```js
 <!-- Switch Button for online/offline status -->
    <div v-if="user.role=== 'accountant' || user.role=== 'supervisor'">
      <v-chip v-if="onlineStatusValue" color="green" class=" d-flex row-pointer" small dense @click="statusUpdated()">
        <v-icon x-small color="green darken-4">mdi-circle-medium</v-icon>
        <p class="white--text font-style-paragraph pl-2 pt-1">Online</p>
      </v-chip>
      <v-chip v-else color="red" class=" d-flex row-pointer" small dense @click="statusUpdated()">
        <v-icon x-small color="red darken-4">mdi-circle-medium</v-icon>
        <p class="white--text font-style-paragraph pl-2 pt-1">Offline</p>
      </v-chip>
    </div>
```

Method which updates the state

```js
  methods: {
    /**
     * This method is used to test i.e either the user is online/offline
     * Socket integration method used in it
     **/
    statusUpdated() {
      clearTimeout(this.userStatusInterval)
      if (this.onlineStatusValue === false) {
        if(this.role === 'supervisor'){
           window.open("/supervisor-ticketpool");
          // this.$router.push("/supervisor-ticketpool")
        }
        socket.emit("userConnected", this.user._id);
        this.userStatusInterval = setTimeout(function () {
          EventBus.$emit('user-status-online');
        }, 1000);
      }
      else{
        if(this.role === 'supervisor'){
          this.$router.push("/");
        }
        socket.emit("userDisconnected", this.user._id);
      }
 /* ----> updates the online Status  */  
        this.$store.commit("auth/setOnlineStatus", !this.onlineStatusValue);
    },
}
```

This method does update the state correctly but only of the Tab which is currently in focus. If I have multiple Tabs opened, the change in state on the Focused tab, will not be reflected in the other tabs (which are currently not in focus). I want all of my unfocused tabs' state `this.onlineStatusValue` to be updated whenever the state `this.onlineStatusValue` gets updated in the focused tab (want the state to be on the same page for all my tabs).

Answer (score 0):

Probably a good candidate for a state management. You can change and access stored value from any tab. Check [Pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/) out.